# Prove that $J(t)\geq \gamma K(t)$.

Tags: functions

Let $J(t), K(t)$ two positive and increasing functions defined in $t\in[0,+\infty)$. If $J(0)\geq \frac{1}{2} K(0)$ prove that $J(t)\geq \gamma K(t)$ with $\gamma\in\mathbb R$ and $\gamma\geq 1/2$.
Are these assumptions sufficient to prove the thesis? And in what way?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your statement is not true under those  assumptions. Consider for example:

$$J(x)=x+1 \qquad K(x)=3x$$

Those functions verify that $J(0)=1>\frac{1}{2}K(0)=0$ but $\gamma K(x) = 3\gamma x \ge \frac{3}{2}x > x+1 \quad \forall x > 2$.  If you want to prove a statement like that one you will probably need to impose some condition on the derivatives of the functions.

Comment: Thank you. For example $J'(0)>K'(0)$?

Comment: No, that wouldn't work either. Consider as $J$ one function which increases very rapidly at first but then approaches assymptotically one constant value and $K$ a linear function of $t$ as before. If you make a drawing it would be clear.

Comment: Ok, is possible to think of some hypotheses on the derivative?